# Sum Column of Integers Based on Timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I am using PostgreSQL version 8.1.  I have a table as follows:

```
          datetime     |    usage 
-----------------------+----------
2015-12-16 02:01:45+00 |    71.615
2015-12-16 03:14:42+00 |    43.000
2015-12-16 01:51:43+00 |    25.111
2015-12-17 02:05:26+00 |    94.087
```

I would like to add the integer values in the `usage` column based on the date in the `datetime` column.

Simply, I would like the output to look as below:

```
          datetime     |    usage 
-----------------------+----------
2015-12-16             |    139.726
2015-12-17             |    94.087
```

I have tried `SELECT dateTime::DATE, usage, SUM(usage) FROM tableName GROUP BY dateTime::DATE, lngusage;` which does not perform as expected.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DATE_TRUNC('day', datetime)` [according to the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query should give you the desired result:

```
select to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as time, sum(usage)
from table
group by time
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is for postgreSQL, I see you added MySQL also.

```
SELECT
  dt
  SUM(usage),
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('day', datetime) dt,
    usage
  FROM
    tableName
) t
GROUP BY
  dt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT to_char(datetime, 'format'), sum(usage)
FROM table
group by to_char(datetime, 'format')
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition you could a window function.

```
SELECT DATETIME
,SUM(USAGE) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(datetime AS DATE) ORDER BY datetime) AS Usage
FROM TableName
```